# redirect and send variable via js

Tags: php, javascript, variables, redirect

This is tricky..

I have two sites. Site A and site B. On another site (any site) I post an affiliate link which takes you to site A where I have a script that redirects to site B (so the first link goes to site B after going through site A)

On site A, I have a variable which I'm trying to pass to site B but without putting it in the browser URL, e.g. `http://www.siteB.com/?var=blabla`

I was advised to try and use js to post the variables to site B. I tried putting this code in site A..

```
<body onLoad="submit_form();">
<form name="myform" action="http://www.siteb.com" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="var" value="blabla"> 
</form>

<script language="javascript">
  <!--
  function submit_form() 
  {
    document.myform.submit()
  }
  -->
</script>
```

and on site B I tried using GET to get teh variable but nothing shows up

```
$var = $_GET['var'];
echo $var;
```

Must I somehow put the js var in header() ? I'm lost..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your form is `POST`-ing the data, but you're trying to access the data from the `$_GET` array.

Try this:

```
$var = $_POST['var'];
echo $var;
```

`$_POST` contains data sent via POST, `$_GET` contains data sent via GET.